# Deploying app to Heroku - dm-core and dm-postgres-adapter issue?

Tags: heroku, datamapper, rails-postgresql

I am having an issue deploying to Heroku - here is the strange line of my log file:

`/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in 'require': no such file to load -- dm--adapter (LoadError)`

Notice the last item there - it says `dm--adapter`... shouldn't there be a 'postgres' in between there?!

Does anyone know what's up?

Comment: Just happened to me locally with Grape